# How can I send a HTML page which contains pictures?

Tags: python, html, tcp

I've written a TCP server, which functions perfectly with web pages which only contain text, but I cant seem to send HTML files which contain pictures. How am I supposed to do it?

```
DIR = "D:/wwwroot/"
SERVER = ("server_address", 8820) #server_address replaced with my IP
PHRASE_CHART = "D:/wwwroot/phrase_chart.txt"
CONTENT_TYPE_CHART = "D:/wwwroot/content_type_chart.txt"
DEFAULT_PAGE = "D:/wwwroot/main.html"

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(SERVER)
client_counter = 0
while client_counter <= 10:
    server_socket.listen(1)
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    client_counter += 1
    while True:
        try:
            request = client_socket.recv(1024)
            request = request[0:request.find("/r/n/r/n")]
            if request[0:3] == "GET":
                file_name = request[5: request.find("HTTP/1.1") - 1]
                if os.path.isfile(DIR + file_name):
                    page = open(DIR + file_name)
                    data = ""
                    for line in page:
                        data += line
                    client_socket.send(data)
                elif file_name == "":
                    page = open(DEFAULT_PAGE)
                    data = ""
                    for line in page:
                        data += line
                    client_socket.send(data)
                else:
                    client_socket.send("")
            else:
                client_socket.close()
        except socket.error:
            break
client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

Comment: A browser will issue another HTTP GET request for images (and anything else) that the HTML document links to, currently you seem to assume that each incoming request is for a text resource.  You should examine the HTTP request made to your server using capture tools or your browsers network inspector.

Comment: If you open your browser's development console you can see how a page is loaded through multiple HTTP GET requests from a popular server of your choice.